# Chrome 35 webkitNotifications undefined on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, webkit-notifications

Since the last update of Chrome to 35 the following peace of code returns `undefined`:

```
console.log(window.webkitNotifications);
```

Is this just a temporary bug or there something changed? I couldn't find anything about it.. It worked before very well...

I don't block anything, all website's are allowed to show Notifications according my Privacy settings in Chrome.

Comment: It's not a bug. `webkitNotifications` is deprecated. Here's the new Notification API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Web_Notifications (Ps: most new APIs in HTML5 are currently not stable/reliable and will probably be modified in the future. Examples include the flex model in CSS3 and WebSQL, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look further into that :)